# Should we have a "Culture Tour"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, new-users

The [Welcome Tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) takes new users through the *mechanics* of the SE sites.

Should we have an additional tour that explains key *behaviours* that are expected of the AskUbuntu community?

Things like:

- (Thoroughly) Search first
- Be specific in questions (and show how to get output and/or screenshots)
- Don't copy and paste between questions or answers
- Duplicates should be marked duplicate
- What's on-topic here and what's off-topic?
- Where should I go for closely-related / borderline questions?
- Why would a question be off-topic?
- Upvote regularly
- Overall hierarchy of users and features
- What moderators do
- What are Moderator Elections?

These are all things that could (and do) exist as meta questions, and most of them would overlap across all SE sites, but it might help to reduce people's presumptions and have something to refer to when new users have issues.  If you already took the Culture Tour on another site, it could also skip over things you (should) already know.

> Oh, I see you haven't got the "culture" tag.  You might find it
>   helpful to take the AskUbuntu Culture Tour.

It could also be something we can review rather than there being a somewhat loose idea of these kinds of things.

Comment: I'm pretty sure all of this is described in the Help Center except maybe searching before asking (although implied by the existence of dupes) and mod elections.

Comment: True, but I have to be *seeking it out* to find it in the help centre.  This is more like the Welcome tour to manage expectations of behaviour that might not be obvious to new users.